# HTML element does not fade in using jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a small web project as you can see here: http://seegermattijs.be/pickone/
When you insert two items, the pick one button should fade in. Unfortunately it does not fade. I use the following code:

```
$('.bigBtn').fadeIn('slow');
```

and in the begininning I make .bigBtn invisible:

```
$('.bigBtn').hide()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using CSS animations and jQuery animations on the same elements, and you're not doing what we told you to do in the previous question you asked, as the elements you're appending are still not hidden.

Comment: kindly show as html as well i am guessing you should use id instead of class.

Comment: I tested `$('.bigBtn').fadeIn('slow');` in debugger, it's work. Did you add your code ?

Comment: add `;` in `$('.bigBtn').hide()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CSS transitions that you have applied to *every* element on the page (very beginning of your `css/main.css`):

```or-tag-here
* {
    transition: all .1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
}
```

are clashing with the jQuery fade animation.

Remove the CSS transitions from your button using something like:

```or-tag-here
.bigBtn {
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
}
```

(Or better still, only apply them where you want them in the first place).

Your `.fadeIn('slow')` will then work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add').on('click',function(){
    var items = $('.items > h2').length;
    if(items >= 2) {
       $('.bigBtn').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```